# Master Data Services 2016 cross domain users management issue

Tags: sql-server-2016, master-data-services

I have a scenario where MDS admin users and MDS application pool exist in domain **A** , normal MDS users exist in domain **B**.

While this scenario worked with MDS 2012 after upgrade to MDS 2016 I am not able to navigate to functional area in MDS user security management with **A\admin** user- it yields "Access is Denied". Other areas in user security management work. The only information I could find in MDS log is: ***The user name or password is incorrect.***

I thought it might be related to fact that cross forest domain roaming is disabled and those **B** domain users cannot have fully imported profiles on MDS machine. I have enabled it, forced GPO refresh - doesn't work

I tried with MDS database and application created by user from domain **B** - doesn't work

Any ideas how to investigate or fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like workaround is to create local user group for MDS users and then add this group to MDS.

This way you can change all permissions for a group. Each domain user will get created with all settings inherited from group.